# Why is $Z_2 \times Z_3 \times Z_4$ not isomorphic to $Z_{24}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

> *Why is $Z_2 \times Z_3 \times Z_4$ not isomorphic to $Z_{24}$?*

I had written this as a step in solving a problem on my math exam, and my teacher marked it as incorrect.

But I'm not sure as to why it's wrong, because $2$, $3$ and $4$ share no common factor?

Also, I'm sorry about the editing. I'm new to this site and not sure how to fix it.

Comment: 2 and 4 are not coprime.

Comment: Do 2 and 4 share no common factor?

Comment: One has an element of order $8$, and the other does not.

Comment: Wow. I feel completely idiotic. I can't believe I made such a stupid mistake. Thank you so much for the clarification!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Certainly $2$ and $4$ share a common factor, namely $2$ itself.

Anyway, the groups are nonisomorphic, e.g., because $Z_{24}$ contains elements of order $24$ but the elements of $Z_2 \times Z_3 \times Z_4 \cong Z_2 \times Z_{12}$ all have order at most $12$.

Comment: Wow. I feel completely idiotic. I can't believe I made such a stupid mistake. Thank you so much for the clarification!

Comment: It happens to the best of us. :) I'm glad you find my answer useful.

Answer (score 0):

$\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_4$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_{12}$. But now $2, 12$ are not coprime, so you have that it is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{24}$.